# How to connect Spartan-6 with ISE 14.2 on Ubuntu

Tags: fpga, xilinx, ise

I bought my first FPGA and I'm trying to implement a simple VHDL program on it, but I don't know how to connect it's [Atlys board](http://www.digilentinc.com/Products/Detail.cfm?NavPath=2,400,836&Prod=ATLYS) to ISE 14.2. I'm using Ubuntu 64-bit.

Comment: There's a 14.2 already? I barely finished downloading 14.1! :P

Comment: it doesn't really help  !

Comment: Is it on a dev board - if so which one? Do you have a JTAG programmer? (e.g. Xilinx [Platform Cable USB](http://www.xilinx.com/onlinestore/program_solutions.htm))

Comment: I don't have JTAG  programmer and the the FPGA is on a dev board it's the Atlys

Comment: You will need to find a jtag or programmer cable then; since you are running linux pay extra attention to one with decent Linux driver support.  If you have some other configurable clocked serial interface such as is common in an embedded system, there are other ways of loading data too, but generally those take more work to set up.

Comment: What have you tried? Both the Atlys board and Xilinx ISE are two very complex pieces of kit. Have you read the documentation? Have you followed along with the sample projects that ship with your board? If you have a specific question, feel free to ask. In this state, there's not much we can do.

Answer (score 2):

There is a set of Linux drivers by [Michael Gernoth](http://rmdir.de/~michael/xilinx/) to replace the ones provided by Xilinx. I used them with a parallel cable, but they are designed for USB cables originally (though the Digilent USB cables are not in the list, but it might be worth a try).

I also needed to run ISE as root, and to preload the proper libraries. I did a [writeup](http://blog.hendriklipka.de/archives/2012/03/xilinx_ise_under_linux.html) of my experiences, since there were also some other issues.

Answer (score 1):

As Oli Glaser says, (most) parts need a Xilinx programming cable. However this one appears to have a USB port. Use the [Digilent Adept](http://www.digilentinc.com/Products/Detail.cfm?NavPath=2,66,828&Prod=ADEPT2) software provided with the board, specifically the [Digilent Plugin for Xilinx Tools](http://www.digilentinc.com/Products/Detail.cfm?NavPath=2,66,768&Prod=DIGILENT-PLUGIN). However that doesn't list 14.x ISE.